# How do I get the list of assemblies and their versions for composite docker image of ASP.NET runtime?

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core

Here's what [documentation for composite images](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/image-variants.md#composite-net-80) says:

> ASP.NET Core Composite images provide a smaller size on disk while keeping the performance of the default ReadyToRun (R2R) setting. The caveat is that the composite images have tighter version coupling. **This means the final app run on them cannot use handpicked custom versions of the framework and/or ASP.NET assemblies that are built into the composite binary.**

But how do I get the list of these assemblies and their versions?